# Tkinter in Python.. Tic Tac Toe Game.. Error With the Button!

Tags: python, tkinter

Im new at tkinter so im a begginer.. I need help because i was trying to programma Tic Tac Toe .. i wanted to start the game with a heart button as zone the when the player click on that the image has to change in X or O (another gif image)...
So i need a function to help me to switch the image in the button but when i tryed to do it it gave me this error: AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'image'
 this is the part of the code that gives me the problem..

```
class Application(object):

    def __init__(self,fnt2):
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="game.gif")
        self.lab1 = Label(fnt2, text="WELCOME to the GAME")
        self.lab1.image = self.photo
        self.lab1['background']="#BD5151"
        self.lab1['foreground']="#651268"
        self.lab1.image = self.photo
        self.lab1.pack()

        self.lab2= Label(image=self.photo)
        self.lab2.image= self.photo
        self.lab2['background']="#BD5151"
        self.lab2.pack()
        self.imm0 = PhotoImage(file="start.gif")
        self.imm1 = PhotoImage(file="bianco.gif")
        self.imm2 = PhotoImage(file="ics.gif")


        self.Ent = Button(fnt2, text="Click To Enter The GAME")
        self.Ent['relief']="groove"
        self.Ent['command']=self.Ent_Click
        self.Ent.pack()

    def Changepic_1(self):
        imm0 = PhotoImage(file="start.gif")
        imm1 = PhotoImage(file="bianco.gif")
        imm2 = PhotoImage(file="ics.gif")
        if self.Play.image == self.imm0:
            print('ciao')


    def Ent_Click(self):
        fnt2 = Tk()
        fnt2.title("play it!")
        fnt2.resizable(False,False)
        for r in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                self.Play = Button(image = self.imm0, command=self.Changepic_1)
                self.Play.grid(row=r,column=c)
        fnt2.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it with:

```
button.config(image=...)
```

To find out what image it already has, you'll need to compare:

```
button.cget("image") == image.name
```

(Or keep track of its state separately)

Tk isn't object oriented, so although Tkinter tries to make the interface a bit more "Pythonic", it can be a bit awkward.